# Jenkins SVNKit error while connecting to SVN in Linux server post kernel patch upgrade to FP3

Tags: linux, tomcat, svn, jenkins

I upgraded the kernel to patch 3 and now when I run Jenkins I am getting the error below during SVN Update  :

I think the issue may be with Subversion plugin (currently 1.45),SVNKit.
Linux version is SUSE Linux enterprise Server 11(x86_64)
PATCH LEVEl -3
VERSION 11
Subversion Plugin -1.45
Jenkins version -1.534

Error is below:

```
svn: E175002: SSLv3 SSLContext not available
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:754)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    ... 37 more
```

Please help as its blocking my work!

Comment: Take a closer look at the error: > **SSLv3** SSLContext not available

Comment: SSLv3 SSLContext not available error..does it mean I need to install SSLv3 in linux box?

Comment: Some forums suggests to add -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3 during startup

Comment: @bahrep -what can I try here?